# PreferenceManager getDefaultSharedPreferences deprecated in Android Q

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-10.0

`PreferenceManager getDefaultSharedPreferences` is deprecated in [Android 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_10). How do I replace it?

Answer (score 394, accepted):

You can use the Android 10 support library version of [`PreferenceManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/PreferenceManager.html), i.e., `androidx.preference.PreferenceManager` and not `android.preference.PreferenceManager`.

Remember to add the following to your *build.gradle*:

```
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.2.0'
```

Comment: @AbhinavSaxena Yes of course. That's implicit when using a support library. An earlier edit to this answer added the kotlin-only ktx depency; I rolled back that edit because it was kotlin-only.

Comment: This seems to have to be `implementation` not `dependency`?

Comment: Not that that works either: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not find implementation "androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0.

Comment: I'm curious; why did they deprecate that interface, and was some other way of obtaining shared preferences preferred, or was switching to androidx the intent?

Comment: @EdwardFalk I don't know but to me it smells like `getDefaultSharedPreferences()` is collateral damage. Yes, many preferemces-related areas were fragmented so it makes sense to move them to a support library. `getDefaultSharedPreferences()` implementation itself is still the same in both Android platform and AndroidX libraries, so that function did not really need deprecation.

Comment: Where in the build.grandle I add this line?
What happens with older mobile phones if I change "android." to "androidx."?

Comment: What about Xamarin.Android. I've tried AndroidX.Preferences; but it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 202):

Package [`preference`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/preference) provides the `androidx` [PreferenceManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/PreferenceManager.html):

Java: `implementation "androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1"`

Kotlin: `implementation "androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1"`

---

i.e.
change `android.preference.PreferenceManager` to `androidx.preference.PreferenceManager`

---

Also see [PreferenceFragmentCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat), which is the current `PreferenceFragment` class to use.

Comment: Added a direct link to `PreferenceFragmentCompat`, which didn't exist back then... it's usually then next one deprecation problem one might face, when trying to update preferences. The other linked answer was only valid for a limited amount of time.

Comment: Can we use in APIs before API 29?

Comment: @H.Karatsanov yes, you can.

Answer (score 25):

If you're just saving and retrieving key-value pairs you can replace:

```
 prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

with:

```
 prefs = getSharedPreferences(
            "my.app.packagename_preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Be sure to use the right file name for the new implementation or your users will lose access to everything saved with getDefaultSharedPreferences(!). The following will get the file name getDefaultSharedPreferences uses:

```
getPackageName() + "_preferences"
```

Comment: This is a good answer, as context.getPackageName() also works in modules and retrieves the application-id.

Comment: Also note ; for java and not for Kotlin. Kotlin it would look like something like getSharedPreferences(applicationContext.packageName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

Comment: Nice way to avoid unnecessarily using androidx.preference.PreferenceManager just to access getDefaultSharedPreferences.

Comment: also If your are calling it from outside an activity, use "context.getSharedPreferences(context.packageName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)"

Answer (score 12):

Use [Jetpack DataStore](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore), It is a data storage solution that allows you to store key-value pairs or typed objects with protocol buffers. DataStore uses Kotlin coroutines and Flow to store data asynchronously, consistently,
and transactionally.

> ### If you're currently using SharedPreferences to store data, consider
> migrating to DataStore instead.

Setup

```
dependencies {
        implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore:1.0.0"
}
```

It also has support for RxJava2 & RxJava3.

Comment: Sometimes we have one choice and it's only shareprefrences, for example when you use third party libraries that receive shareprefrences as parameter called on some method. open street map configuration load method is a case.

Answer (score 3):

Quote from `PreferenceManager` [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager):

> This class was deprecated in API level 29.
>   Use the AndroidX [Preference Library](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/package-summary.html) for consistent behavior across all devices. For more information on using the AndroidX Preference Library see [Settings](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html).

Comment: What wasn't consistent about the original one?

Comment: @androiddeveloper it is obvious, missing letter x in the package name

Answer (score 3):

#### Kotlin library

```
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1'
```

#### Kotlin use

```
Configuration.getInstance().load(this, androidx.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this))
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is deprecated.

> Use the AndroidX Preference Library for consistent behavior across all devices. For more information on using the AndroidX Preference Library see Settings.

Follow this -

[PreferenceManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager)

Answer (score 1):

You can import this library at app level gradle

```
implementation "androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1"
```

Then remove imported file from class where you create "PreferenceManager"
Press Alt+Enter and import androidx hope you get latest version of preference manager.

Answer (score 1):

```
implementation "androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1"
```

class file PrivateSharedPreferences;

```
class PrivateSharedPreferences(context: Context) {
private val file = "com.example.com_shared"
private val key = "private_key"
private var sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(file, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
private val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()

fun save(ok: Boolean) {
    editor.putBoolean(key, ok)
    editor.apply()
}

fun read() : Boolean {
    return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, false)
}
```

}

read from fragment or adapter;

```
PrivateSharedPreferences(context).read()
```

save

```
PrivateSharedPreferences(context).save(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to import androidx library like

```
import androidx.preference.PreferenceManager
```

For kotlin DSL:

```
implementation("androidx.preference:preference:1.2.1")
```

For KSP:

```
implementation("androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.2.1")
```

For more info, you can visit official document of [Preference](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/preference).