# How to load Shared Preferences on first Application start

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I'm using an activity called `SettingsActivity` that extends `PreferenceFragmentCompat`. When the application starts for the very first time `MainActivity`, I try to get the preferences through `getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext())` but without success because they are only loaded when I start the Settings activity.

To prove this, I checked the file shared_preferences.xml and it's filled only when I open the `SettingsActivity`.

In this sense, how can I force the loading of the preferences in the `MainActivity`?

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Map<String, ?> allPreferences = getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.applicationContext).getAll();
        Log.d(Class.forName(), allPreferences.isEmpty()); //prints true

        Intent intent_settings = new Intent(activityContext, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent_settings);
     }
}
```

**SettingsActivity**

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey);

        Map<String, ?> allPreferences = getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().getAll();
        Log.d(Class.forName, allPreference.isEmpty()); // prints false
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code?  If you try to get a preference through the key, and it doesn't exist yet, there is a default value.

Comment: @romulus I shared the code now.

Comment: The accepted answer uses a deprecated class. See:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56833657/preferencemanager-getdefaultsharedpreferences-deprecated-in-android-q/56911496

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your activity's `onCreate` place the following code

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
```

reference [Android Developers Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager#setDefaultValues(android.content.Context,%20int,%20boolean))