# Retrofit interface how to add cookies to store data

Tags: android, node.js, session, retrofit2

I have an android studio application that connects to a nodejs backend server with user authentication. I can log in and register from my app but it does not store a session. So I can not get session based functionality yet.

I need to add functionality to store a session. For this how do I do this with the retrofit interface.
I want to log in start a session so I can have user logged in access to other routes on the server.

Or is there another interface for android studio that will allow for cookies and sessions?
**Retrofit interface**

````java
public interface RetrofitInterface {

            
    @POST("/login")
    Call<Login_result> executeLogin(@Body HashMap<String, String> map);
            
    @POST("/signup")
    Call<Void> executeSignup(@Body HashMap<String, String>map);
            
    @POST("/add_data")
    Call<Void> executeAdd_data(@Body HashMap<String, String>map);
            
    @POST("/logout")
    Call<Void> executeLogout(@Body HashMap<String, String>map);
            
    @GET("/test")
    Call<Void> executeTest();

}
**Main code**

```java


/*Updated this*/
    Context context = this;

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(new OkhttpClient.builder()
                        .addInterceptor(new ReceivedCookiesInterceptor(context)
                                .addInterceptor(new AddCookiesInterceptor(context)
                                ).build())
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();
        retrofitInterface = retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface.class);
````

Log in code

```
    HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
                //map.put("email",emailEdit.getText().toString());//
                map.put("username", usernameEdit.getText().toString());
                map.put("password", passwordEdit.getText().toString());

                Call<Login_result> call = 
                retrofitInterface.executeLogin(map);//Run the post
                call.enqueue(new Callback<Login_result>()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<Login_result> call, Response<Login_result> response) {
                        if(response.code() == 200)
                        {
                            /*Login_result result = response.body();
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                            builder1.setTitle(result.getUsernname());
                            builder1.setMessage(result.getEmail());

                            builder1.show();*/
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Logged in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        }else if(response.code() == 404)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Incorrect usernanme or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<Login_result> call, Throwable t) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: does this questions ans is switable for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418809/add-cookies-to-retrofit-2-request

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to create an two `interceptors` and store the cookie information in Shared Preferences

```
public class ReceivedCookiesInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private Context context;
    public ReceivedCookiesInterceptor(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());

        if (!originalResponse.headers("Set-Cookie").isEmpty()) {
            HashSet<String> cookies = (HashSet<String>) PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getStringSet("PREF_COOKIES", new HashSet<String>());

            for (String header : originalResponse.headers("Set-Cookie")) {
                cookies.add(header);
            }

            SharedPreferences.Editor memes = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit();
            memes.putStringSet("PREF_COOKIES", cookies).apply();
            memes.commit();
        }

        return originalResponse;
    }
}
```

And then reverse to add cookies to the outgoing request

```
public class AddCookiesInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    public static final String PREF_COOKIES = "PREF_COOKIES";
    private Context context;

    public AddCookiesInterceptor(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request.Builder builder = chain.request().newBuilder();

        HashSet<String> preferences = (HashSet<String>) PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getStringSet(PREF_COOKIES, new HashSet<String>());

        Request original = chain.request();
        if(original.url().toString().contains("distributor")){
            for (String cookie : preferences) {
                builder.addHeader("Cookie", cookie);
            }
        }

        return chain.proceed(builder.build());
    }
}
```

Which then you would need to change your Retrofit instance to the below

```
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(new OkhttpClient.builder()
                        .addInterceptor(new ReceivedCookiesInterceptor(context)
                        .addInterceptor(new AddCookiesInterceptor(context) 
                ).build())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        retrofitInterface = retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface.class);
```

Comment: I presume the interceptors will be their own class files and just getting imported to the main code when I call my retrofit interface?

Comment: @ThomasMorris Yeah

Comment: My issue is in my retrofit builder I dont have the class okhttpClient is that an import?

Comment: Add these two to your build.gradle

   ` //okhttp
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.4.0'`

Comment: Still says okhtppClient is missing and need to create class. How do I import it? Also the context i presume needs changing to this?

Comment: @ThomasMorris No you need the context to access the Shared Preferences

To import add 

 //okhttp 
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.4.0' <-- main
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.4.0' <--- interceptors to see your cookies etc, if you wanted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218746/discussion-between-thomas-morris-and-tdiscott).

Comment: `android.preference.PreferenceManager` is deprecated in favor of `androidx.preference.PreferenceManager` as mentioned here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/56833739/442665